# advanced programming in the unix example ls(1) command error

Tags: c, unix

```
#include "apue.h"
#include <dirent.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    DIR     *dp;
    struct dirent *dirp;

    if(argc != 2)
        err_quit("usage: ls directory_name");

    if((dp=opendir(argv[1])) == NULL)
        err_sys("can't open %s", argv[1]);

    while((dirp = readdir(dp)) !=NULL)
        printf("%s\n", dirp->d_name);

    closedir(dp);

    exit(0);

}
```

I downloaded apue.h file and it is in the current directory as my source file. when I try to compile with clang and OS X the following error occurs.

```
    1 warning generated.
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
        "_err_quit", referenced from:
            _main in lsnew-cbcc3e.o
        "_err_sys", referenced from:
            _main in lsnew-cbcc3e.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can someone steer me in the right direction as to what is wrong? does this code only work on 32bit systems?

thanks.

Comment: 'I downloaded apue.h... does it not need an actual library linked in as well?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the examples you are using, but the error you see is a linker error: it means that, although the header file `apue.h` has declared that the functions exist, nothing has actually defined the functions.

They should be provided in another `.c` file, perhaps `apue.c`? Then you would include it in your compiled program by listing it on the clang command-line along with your `lsnew.c`:

```
clang -o lsnew apue.c lsnew.c
```

I can't tell you where you might find the required file, but it should probably be in the same place that you found `apue.h`.

Comment: These functions might already be compiled into a static or a dynamic library, then you'll have to link with them.

Comment: @SHG I emailed the author and was told to use the make file. He said there was no .c source file. I am trying to learn all this. I went into the directory with the file that says make and I typed make on the terminal. A bunch of things happened but I do not know what to do now. I don't know if I did it right.

Answer (score 0):

Both undefined symbols can be replaced with own implementation.

Lines

```
if(argc != 2)
    err_quit("usage: ls directory_name");
```

can be written as:

```
if(argc != 2) {
    printf("usage: ls directory_name");
    return 1;
}
```

Lines

```
if((dp=opendir(argv[1])) == NULL)
    err_sys("can't open %s", argv[1]);
```

can be written as:

```
if((dp=opendir(argv[1])) == NULL) {
    printf("can't open %s", argv[1]);
    return 1;
}
```